# Javascript animation too fast

Tags: javascript, animation, html

I am trying to write a javascript app which sorts dynamically created divs on a webpage, everything works and it sorts it all as it should, however I want it to animate the divs as they change position due to being sorted, I have code to do this but it moves way too fast, the only way I can see the divs move is if I put an alert in the animation code which looks like this :

```
function moveAnimation(to,from){

       mover1.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,100,175,0.8)";
       mover2.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,100,175,0.8)";
       mover1.style.top = parseInt(mover1.style.top) + 10 + 'px';
       mover2.style.top = parseInt(mover2.style.top) - 10 + 'px';
       from = parseInt(mover1.style.top);

       if(from != to && from < to)
       {
        //alert("TO : " + to + " From : " + from); //This makes it pause so that I can see the divs move
        animate = setTimeout(moveAnimation(to,from),1000)

       }
       else
       {
       //alert("RET");
        return;
       }

}
```

And i call it simply like this :

```
mover1 = document.getElementById(moving1.id);
mover2 = document.getElementById(moving2.id);
var from = parseInt(in1.style.top);
var to = parseInt(in2.style.top);

moveAnimation(to,from);
```

When the alert is in place I can see them move frame by frame and it's doing exactly what I want, however it all happens in the blink of an eye with the divs suddenly being sorted, I would like to see them slowly move, any ideas on why my code isn't doing that?

Comment: A `setTimeout` isn't an animation. You're saying "delay 1 second, then do this".

Comment: As isherwood points out, there is no animation going on here at all. You either need to manually loop through some logic moving each div a few pixels each time (this is where you'd use a setTimeout to pause between each movement), use a JS library that has animation (such as jQuery), or--probably the best route--use CSS transitions to handle the animations.

Comment: Ah I assumed I was moving the first and second divs by 10px up and down respectively with this line "mover1.style.top = parseInt(mover1.style.top) + 10 + 'px';" and "mover2.style.top = parseInt(mover2.style.top) - 10 + 'px';" every 1000msec. Are you saying I'd need to put those 2 lines in their own function and call that with timeout?

Comment: @Gman unless you have a loop that you aren't showing us, that setTimeout just happens once. So it will move your object by 10px once. If you want to move it 10px repeatedly over time, then you need to stick it in a loop. I'd still strongly recommend you consider using CSS transitions, however. It will be a much smoother animation (and more performant).